# cassandra cql query, read WHERE condition from method

Tags: java, cassandra, cql

I have a java method like:

```
public ServiceCall<NotUsed, PSequence<Item>> getSomeItems(UUID itemId) {
    return (req) -> {
        CompletionStage<PSequence<Item>> result = db.selectAll("SELECT * FROM item WHERE itemId=?")
                .thenApply(...)}
}
```

the `itemId` should be passed as a parameter in method signature, how can I use it in the query ?

Comment: which library are you using?

Comment: @HaifengZhang com.lightbend.lagom.javadsl.persistence.cassandra.CassandraSession

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](http://www.lagomframework.com/documentation/1.1.x/java/api/com/lightbend/lagom/javadsl/persistence/cassandra/CassandraSession.html#selectAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-), the `selectAll` method receives the parameters via a varargs.

Example:

```
result = db.selectAll("SELECT * FROM item WHERE itemId=?", 5)
```